# How to resolve 'path is wrong' compile error include GTKmm 3.0

Tags: c++, eclipse, g++, gtkmm

I have changed the command line pattern in the GCC C++ compiler to

```
${COMMAND}  'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0' ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} 
${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

As well as the Command line pattern in the GCC C++ Linker. I then added the paths

```
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0
/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0
/usr/include/glibmm-2.4
```

To includes (http://milindapro.blogspot.nl/2012/10/create-gui-with-gtkmm-setup-eclipse-for.html). Compiling however tells me that some path is either wrong or missing:

```
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++  'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0' -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -         I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -    MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
g++: error: pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0: No such file or directory
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score -2):

apparently, ' is not the same as `. Gosh